# File is read on Windows but not on a Linux container?

Tags: java, docker, stream, java-stream, bufferedreader

Like the title says I'm not able to read the contents of a file (csv file) while running the same code on a linux container

```
private Set<VehicleConfiguration> loadConfigurations(Path file, CodeType codeType) throws IOException {

    log.debug("File exists? " + Files.exists(file));
    log.debug("Path " + file.toString());
    log.debug("File " + file.toFile().toString());
    log.debug("File absolute path " + file.toAbsolutePath().toString());

    String line;
    Set<VehicleConfiguration> configurations = new HashSet<>(); // this way we ignore duplicates in the same file
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.toFile()))){
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            configurations.add(build(line, codeType));
        }
    }


    log.debug("Loaded " + configurations.size() + " configurations");
    return configurations;
}
```

The logs return "true" and the path for the file in both systems (locally on windows and on a linux docker container). On windows it loads "15185 configurations" but on the container it loads "0 configurations".

The file exists on linux, I use bash and check it myself. I use the head command and the file has lines.

Before this I tried with Files.lines like so:

```
var vehicleConfigurations = Files.lines(file)
            .map(line -> build(line, codeType))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

But this has a problem (on container only) regarding the contents. It reads the file but not the whole file, it reaches a given line (say line 8000) and does not read it completely (reads about half a line before the comma separator). Then I get a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because my build method tries to split then line and I access index 1 (which it doesn't have, only 0):

```
private VehicleConfiguration build(String line, CodeType codeType) {
    String[] cells = line.split(lineSeparator);
    var vc = new VehicleConfiguration();
    vc.setVin(cells[0]);
    vc.setCode(cells[1]);
    vc.setType(codeType);
    return vc;
}
```

What could be the issue? I don't understand how the same code (in Java) works on Windows but not on a Linux container. It makes no sense.

I'm using Java 11. The file is copied using volumes in a docker-compose file like this:

```
    volumes:
  - ./file-sources:/file-sources
```

I then copy the file (using cp command on the linux container) from file-sources to /root because that's where the app is listening for new files to arrive. File contents are then read with the methods I described. Example file data (does not have weird characters):

[image: file contents]

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Tried with newBufferedReader method, same result (works on windows, doesn't work on linux container):

```
  private Set<VehicleConfiguration> loadConfigurations(Path file, CodeType codeType) throws IOException {
    String line;
    Set<VehicleConfiguration> configurations = new HashSet<>(); // this way we ignore duplicates in the same file
    try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file)){
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            configurations.add(build(line, codeType));
        }
    }

    log.debug("Loaded " + configurations.size() + " configurations");
    return configurations;
}
```

wc -l in the linux container (in /root) returns: 15185 hard_001.csv

Update: This is no solution but I found out that by dropping the files directly on the file-sources folder and make that folder the folder that the code listens to, the files are read. So basically, it seems the problem is more apparent with using cp/mv inside the container to another folder. Maybe the file is read before it is fully copied/moved and that's why it reads 0 configurations?

Comment: Is the file in the docker container empty? How is the file copied to the container? Is there a chance the file has not been written completely when the code to read runs?

Comment: Like I said in the main post. It is not empty. I used head/cat/ commands to check that it isn't empty myself by running bash on the container. The file is copied from another folder in the container. It is put in the original folder with docker-compose volumes.

Comment: *The file is copied from another folder* - When/how does this happen?

Comment: I do it myself using cp command on the docker container: cp filename /root

I then confirm that the file exists and has contents in /root. will add this info on main post. thanks

Comment: If you use `wc -l` in the Linux container to count the lines of the file (as it appears in /root), what does that tell you?

Comment: wc -l in the linux container (in /root) returns: 15185 hard_001.csv

Comment: Well, there *is* something weird in the file if on Windows it reads exactly 15000 configurations, but `wc` on Linux thinks there are 15185 lines.  One possibility would be a few bare newlines, which Linux will recognize as line terminators, but Windows normally will not.

Comment: Oh sorry. It reads the exact same lines on windows. I said 15000 by mistake. Updated main post

Comment: There definitely seems to be something weird going on here, but it's likely contextual.  I would suggest pulling out this config-parsing code to the smallest possible standalone program, and using that to confirm that it works on a non-containerized Linux system, or maybe on WSL.  And if for some reason it doesn't work there then that will give you something easier to debug, and something closer to a [mre] that we could get a handle on here.

Comment: In particular, I don't see how the code presented could log 0 configurations loaded unless the file it was reading were completely empty.  Otherwise, the `BufferedReader` would read at least one line or else throw an exception, and if the former then `build()` would provide at least one configuration object or else throw an exception itself.  There is no `catch` block anywhere in the method, so if any exception were thrown then the last `log.debug()` would not be reached.

Comment: As a side note, when your parameter is a `Path`, you should use `Files.newBufferedReader(Path…)` instead of forcing the default filesystem via `new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.toFile()))`.

Comment: Yes, I already changed the code to do that.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few methods in java you should never use. ever.

`new FileReader(File)` is one of them.

Any time that you have a thing that represents bytes and somehow chars or Strings fall out, or vice versa? Don't ever use those, unless the spec of said method explicitly points out that it always uses a pre-set charset. Almost all such methods use the 'system default charset' which means that the operation depends on the machine you run it on. That is shorthand for 'this will fail, and your tests won't catch it'. Which you don't want.

Which is why you should never use these things.

FileReader has been fixed (there is a second constructor that takes a charset), but that's only since JDK11. You already have the nice new API, why do you switch back to the dinky old File API? Don't do that.

All the various methods in Files, such as `Files.newBufferedReader`, are specced to do UTF-8 if you don't specify (in that way, Files is more useful, and unlike most other java core libraries). Thus:

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file)) {
```

which is just.. better.. than your line.

Now, it'll probably still fail on you. But that's good! It'll **also** fail on your dev machine. Most likely, the file you are reading is not, in fact, in UTF_8. This is the likely guess; most linuxen are deployed with a UTF_8 default charset, and most dev machines are not; if your dev machine is working and your deployment environment isn't, the obvious conclusion is that your input file is not UTF_8. It does not need to be what your dev machine has a default either; something like ISO_8859_1 will never throw exceptions, but it will read gobbledygook instead. Your code may seem to work (no crashes), but the text you read is still incorrect.

Figure out what text encoding you got, and then specify it. If it's ISO_8859_1, for example:

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {
```

and now your code no longer has the 'works on some machines but not on others' nature.

Inspect the line where it fails, in a hex editor if you have to. I bet you dollars to donuts there will be a byte there which is 0x80 or higher (in decimal, 128 or higher). Everything up to and including 127 tends to mean the exact same thing in a wide variety of text encodings, from ASCII to any ISO-8859 variant to UTF-8 Windows Cp1252 to macroman to so many other things, so as long as it's all just plain letters and digits, having the wrong encoding is not going to make any difference. But once you get to 0x80 or higher they're all different. Armed with that byte + some knowledge of what character it is supposed to be is usually a good start in figuring out what encoding that text file is in.

NB: If this isn't it, check how the text file is being copied from your dev machine to your deployment environment. Are you *sure* it is the same file? If it's being copied through a textual mechanism, charset encoding again can be to blame, but this time in how the file is written, instead of how your java app reads it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try your suggestions. I will also add more information regarding the file and how it is copied to the main post.
Basically the file is copied using volumes on docker-compose yml and the content of the file is just numbers and english letters.

Comment: Note that 'it does not have weird characters' is something you should doublecheck. Are you sure? Not all weird characters look it. There is the em-dash, the non-breaking space, and a billion other characters that look extremely similar, if not exactly the same, as what you might call a 'normal' character. hex editor proof or your eyeballs cannot be trusted.

Comment: The file is thousands of lines long. I can't be sure, you're right. I've uploaded the file to an online hex editor to see if I can see something out of the ordinary. However, I don't understand much about this. I'm trying to check if there's a byte 0x80 or higher like you said. I'm using this: https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/
I've searched for 0x80. Found nothing. Anyway, I still have to try the suggested methods. Will give feedback asap.

Comment: So yeah, I tried with the new method and still the same result (works on dev windows machine but not on linux container). Added information to the main post.